# Display multiple select item using dropdown list

Tags: angular, dropdown

I want to create a list of  using select option field, and display it in a table.I want to add also a delete button to delete the seledted, but I didn't create the methode yet.
The problem is that I always get the last selected item.

**component.ts**

```
types = ['début', 'intermédiaire', 'fin'];
selectedType: string;
selectedState: string;
stateType: Array<StateType>;
// get the selected type from dropdown list
onTypeSelect(event: any) {
  this.selectedType = event.target.value;
  console.log(this.selectedType);
}

// get the selected state from dropdown list
onStateSelect(event: any) {
  this.selectedState = event.target.value;
  console.log(this.selectedState);
}
addStateType() {
  let stateType = new StateType(this.selectedState, this.selectedType);
  let stateTypes: Array<StateType> = [];
  stateTypes.push(stateType);
  console.log(stateTypes);
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="exampleSelect1">Etat : </label>
    <select align="left" #selectElem class="form-control" (change)="onStateSelect($event)" multiple>
      <option *ngFor="let state of statesName">
        {{state.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="exampleSelect1">Type : </label>
    <select align="right" #selectElem class="form-control" (change)="onTypeSelect($event)" multiple>
      <option *ngFor="let type of types">
        {{type}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="addStateType()" title="add state">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr *ngFor="let stateType of stateTypes">
        <td>{{selectedState}}</td>
        <td>{{selectedType}}</td>
        <button title="delete">
          <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
        </button>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `stateTypes` have all the states in an array?

Comment: stateTypes should take all the couples state,type. but I get only the last selected couple [StateType] 0 : StateType {name: "état 5", type: "fin"}

Comment: should I have to add a loop to save the selected couple state,type in the list stateTypes????

Comment: any help Please !